# Long-term stay in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, accommodation

I have been struggling to find concise answers and need to come to a decision regarding my travel.

To briefly summarize my situation, I have recently been hired by a company that has offices both in the US and in the UK. I am a US citizen and my girlfriend of over a year is attending university in the UK. Since I have recently finished university and started working, I would like to live with her in the UK while she completes the remainder of her degree.

I know that I am allowed to work in the UK since the company exists in both countries and I will be paid in USD. The company is also ok with me working remotely from the UK, especially since that will put me closer to the software development team.

Unfortunately, since I am so recently hired, I'm not allowed to begin the visa process for a work permit for 4 weeks.

Here are the concerns that I have:

- Can I rent a flat or other accommodation with my girlfriend?
- Am I allowed to "live" in said flat while working remotely with the US branch?
- If I apply for a long-term visitor visa (2/5/10 years), must I leave every 6 months?
- If so, how long must I remain out of the UK before re-entry?
- Will staying in the UK on a visitor visa damage my chances when applying for a work permit?
- Can I transition from a visitor visa into a work permit?

I do not plan on staying in the UK permanently, only to spend time with my partner while she finishes school. Once she is done (1-2 years time), we will return to the US. During that time, I will need to rent. Hotels will be a financial impossibility for that amount of time.

Finally, to clarify:

- I will be paid in US dollars, not in British Pounds.
- I will be working remotely as an employee of the US branch and act as liaison with other employees in the UK and neighboring European area.
- I will not be seeking permanent residency.
- I will return to the US after my girlfriend has completed her degree
- I would like to minimize time spent away from her.

  - I do not wish to anger the Home Office and risk being banned from the UK.

Comment: The premise is incorrect.  Being employed in the US by a company that also operates in the UK does not authorize you to work in the UK.  You need an appropriate work authorization in the form of a visa.  A visitor visa will not suffice.  A work visa is unlikely to be granted unless the company employs you in the UK as a UK-based employee in compliance with UK labor law.

Comment: @Chase Walden Even in the circumstances you describe IMHO you will not be able to use a long term Standard Visitor Visa to spend the amount of time you are indicating in the UK, since you will effectively be living and working there. See v4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules relating to visiting the U.K. for frequent or extended periods. The UK has no fixed period for ‘visa runs’, a rule of thumb being to spend at least the same amount of time out of the U.K. as in it.

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  Perhaps we can get a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: The appropriate visa is [Tier 2 ICT](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa) and the [UK company the licensed sponsor](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/734335/2018-08-16-tier-25-register-sponsors.pdf)

Comment: Forget it. You're courting disaster by attempting to do what you're planning. At some point you will be stopped at immigration and/or banned. UK Border Force/Immigration are among the worst of the worst when it comes to throwing the book at you.

Comment: Where were your parents and grandparents born?

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie I did not once say I was going to follow through with working on a visitor visa. I laid out my situation and what I thought would be the right course of action. My company has an office there and we frequently have business trips, so I wasn't sure if I could just remain there. My bosses even said that I could probably just work from there since I am being paid in USD and not depriving a UK citizen of a job. I am only bringing money into the UK, which is why I thought I would ask

Comment: @Seamus Not in the UK sadly, all of them are US born. One of my grandparents lived in the UK during her childhood, but none of them hold citizenship

Comment: @phoog the premise I had regarding working in the UK may have been mis-stated, but regarding the frequent trips my co-workers and I have to the UK office for business reasons is why I stated as such.

Comment: @ChaseWalden indeed. The line between your frequent trips as a business visitor and what you propose is somewhat blurry, but I doubt there's much question that the proposal is well on the wrong side of that line. The UK is not only protecting local jobs but also *you* (from being employed in the UK under substandard conditions) and its tax revenue, national health service, and the like.

Comment: @ChaseWalden You cannot **just work from the UK** even if you're being paid in the USA. Things don't work that way is what we are explaining.

Comment: @ChaseWalden: What some fail to remember is this: the UK is still an EU member at this time. What that means is that if one of your parents or grandparents were born in (or perhaps even had citizenship in) a EU country, that EU country may grant you citizenship. Ireland is an example of such a country, and there are others. And if you have citizenship in ***any*** EU country, you may remain in the UK for as long as you wish. The "exit" hasn't been ratified as yet, but one of the terms the EU laid down firmly early on was that there would be no expulsions of EU citizens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some answers:

> If I apply for a long term visitor visa (2/5/10 year), must I leave every 6 months?

As a US citizen, such a visa is of no use to you.  You can enter the UK as a visitor without a visa.  Having such a visa does not give you any additional ability to stay in the UK, nor to stay for a longer period of time.

One thing that you can't do with a visitor visa, nor as a visa-free visitor, is ["live in the UK for long periods of time through frequent visits"](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).  It is also forbidden to "do paid or unpaid work," which (in practice, at least) includes remote work.

> Will staying in the UK on a visitor visa damage my chances when applying for a work permit?

Not if you comply with the terms of the visitor visa, but see above.

> Can I transition from a visitor visa into a work permit?

[No](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/switch-to-this-visa).

Your best bet is to get the company to transfer you formally to the UK office, but as a new employee that may be easier said than done.